# Basic question regarding Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, feynman-diagrams

I am considering a muon-electron scattering process:
$$ \mu^{-} + e^{-} \rightarrow \mu^{-} + e^{-}$$
I need to draw all possible diagrams and discuss which diagrams that does **not** contribute to the process. 
I am not quite sure how to advance. This might be traced back to my confusion regarding topological inequivalence of feynman diagrams (but I am not sure).

My question: What disqualifies a diagram from contributing to such process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I find hard to believe that you have to draw **all** the diagrams, since they are infinite. You probably have to draw only the first order ones. Start by drawing the in and out external legs and see in how many ways you can connect them using the two vertices of this theory.

After you are done check your result with this hidden answer to see if you got all of them. $\downarrow$

> There is only 1 diagram

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was the first order diagrams. I found only one diagram aswell.
But will there exist some particle interaction process, where it is possible to draw diagrams that does not contribute to the scattering amplitude? At least that is how the assignment has been formulated.

Comment: Well technically yes, but I don't know if this is what you need. In the scattering amplitude you only consider *amputated* and *connected* diagrams. If you draw the non amputated and non connected diagrams you should find $4$ diagrams and one of them, when amputated, becomes the one you have.